# Volume between hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ and line $x = 2a$ around $y$ axis

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, volume

I'm trying to calculate the volume between the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ and the line $x = 2a$ around the $y$ axis using two methods but I'm getting different answers:

1. Using volume of a solid of revolution with circular-ring method (the usual formula is multiplied by $2$ because half the interval is defined for the integral):
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   V &=& 2 \pi \int_0^{b\sqrt{3}} [(2a)^2 - (\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{y^2+b^2})^2] \, \textrm{d}y \\
   &=& \frac{2 \pi a^2}{b^2} \left[3 b^2 y - \frac{y^3}{3}\right]_0^{b \sqrt{3}} \\
   &=& 4 \sqrt{3} \pi a^2 b \\
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$
2. Using volume of a solid of revolution with cylindrical-shell method:
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   V &=& 2 \pi \int_a^{2a} [x (\frac{2b}{a} \sqrt{x^2 - a^2})] \, \textrm{d}x \\
   &=& 4 \pi a b \left[ \frac{(x^2 - a^2)^{3/2}}{3 a^3} \right]_a^{2a} \\
   &=& 4 \sqrt{3} \pi a b \\
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$

The second answer is the one from my book but I'd really like to understand why the first answer is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second integral is wrong.
\begin{equation*}
  \int \left(x\left(\frac{2b}{a}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right)\right)\,dx
      = \frac{2b}{3a}\int 3x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\,dx 
      = \frac{2b}{3a}(x^2-a^2)^{3/2},
\end{equation*}
so the definite integral is
\begin{equation*}
  V = 2\pi\int_a^{2a} \left(x\left(\frac{2b}{a}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right)\right)\,dx 
    = \frac{4b\pi}{3a}(x^2-a^2)^{3/2}\big\lvert_a^{2a} 
    = 4 \sqrt{3} \pi a^2 b .
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks, so my book was wrong once again. By the way, what technique did you use to integrate $x \sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$?

Comment: Just substitution, essentially, after recognizing that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-a^2)^{3/2} = 3x$. I suppose the "calculus book" way of doing it is to use the substitution $x = a\sec u$ and the identity $\sec^2 u - 1 = \tan^2 u$. What book is this?

Comment: Thanks again, $x = a \sec \theta$ worked. My book is an old edition of The Calculus with Analytic Geometry by Louis Leithold.